# How do I apply middleware in react router 4?

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

How do I pass middleware to my router when using react router 4?

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Thanks!

Pretty standard react redux react-router set-up:

```
export default (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} /> {/* index route */}
        <Route path="/question/" component={Question} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
);
```